# Is FIFOQueue supported in TensorFlow for iOS?

Tags: tensorflow

Is FIFOQueue included with TensorFlow for iOS?

I trained a model, froze it, and optimized for inference, yet I'm getting an error message about FIFOQueue on iOS

"Could not create TensorFlow Graph: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'FIFOQueue' with these attrs. Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels: 
[[Node: fifo_queue = FIFOQueuecapacity=30, component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], container="", shapes=[[640,480,3], [300,1,2], [300,1,4]], shared_name=""]]"

I even tried setting is_training=False in tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/inception_v1.py before training and getting my input_graph.pb . (I tried the checkpoint created with is_training=True)

Is FIFOQueue not supported in TensorFlow for iOS?

Comment: Probably not an iOS-specific issue. It's either a device placement issue (making a hard request for a CPU-only op to be placed on a GPU) or a dtype issue (float/double). I'd guess the first, in which case perhaps [allow_soft_placement](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/using_gpu/) would help?

Answer (score 0):

I added "tensorflow/core/kernels/fifo_queue_op.cc" to tensorflow/contrib/makefile/tf_op_files.txt then ran compile_ios_tensorflow.sh, and the errors went away.